# Rename files using bash/regex?

Tags: regex, bash

I have files named:

```
test-12.5.0_567-release.apk
```

I want them to look like:

```
test-release.apk
```

I realized I can do it with bash:

```
for file in *release.apk; do
  mv "$file" "`basename $file SOMETHING`NEW_FILE_NAME"; done
```

It needs some regex I guess ? How would it look like ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
for file in *release.apk; do
  mv "$file" "${file/-*-/-}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use this:

```
for file in *release.apk; do
    mv "$file" "${file%-*-*}-release.apk"
```

I'm removing `-12.5.0_567-release.apk` and then add `-release.apk`.

However, IMHO [anubhava's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35625586/171318) looks better since it is more precisely doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, with an actual regex and capturing groups. It uses the `=~` operator and the `BASH_REMATCH` array (containing the captured sub groups)

```
for file in *; do
  # check if the filename matches the regex and extract 2 groups
  if [[ $file =~ ([^-]*-).*-([^-]*) ]]; then
    # use the captured groups
    mv "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with the `rename` command:

`rename 's/-*-/-/g' *release.apk`